# Let $L \mid K$ be a cyclic extension with $[L : K] = n$ and $\operatorname{Aut}_K(L) = \langle \sigma \rangle$. Prove that…

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $L \mid K$ be a cyclic extension with $[L : K] = n$ and $\mathrm{Aut}_K(L) = \langle \sigma \rangle$.
> Suppose that $\rho_n(K) = \{ z\in K^* \mid o(z) = n \} \neq \emptyset$ (the set of $n$<sup>th</sup>-primitive roots of unity) and let $z\in \rho_n(K)$. Prove:
>
> 1. For all $\gamma \in L$, the element $\lambda_\gamma = \gamma + z \cdot \sigma(\gamma) + \dotsb + z^{n-1} \sigma^{n-1}(\gamma)$ satisfies $\sigma(\lambda_\gamma) = z^{-1} \lambda_\gamma$.
> 2. (The real problem) There exists $\gamma \in L$ such that $\lambda_\gamma \neq 0$.
> 3. If $\lambda_\gamma \neq 0$, then there exists $a \in K$ such that the minimal polynomial $P_{\lambda_\gamma \mid K}$ equals $x^n - a$, and in this case, we have $L = K(\lambda_\gamma) = K(R_{x^n - a})$.

I proved the first part, it's just some calculation that uses the fact that the orders of $z$ and $\langle \sigma \rangle$ are $n$. The third part is going well with some propositions from my book.

But I can't prove (2). If someone could help with a hint?

Comment: Just a small note: $\lambda_\gamma = 0$ for all $\gamma \in K$, so we need to assume $n > 1$ in order for (2) to hold.

Comment: Please make subject lines complete sentences that describe the general problem. Truncating the first few sentences of the problem is lazy, uninformative, and makes future searches harder.

Comment: $\sigma$ is a $K$-linear map $L\to L$ satisfying $\sigma^n = Id$.

So it can be diagonalized. Let $v_j$ be a basis of eigenvectors, so $\sigma(v_j)=z^{r_j} v_j$. Since $\sigma(v_iv_j)=\sigma(v_i)\sigma(v_j)$ the $z^{r_j}$ form a subgroup of the $n$-th roots of unity. Find a contradiction if this group is smaller than the whole $n$-th roots of unity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known theorem called "linear independence of characters" that provides an easy proof here (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CKK).

In your specific example consider the group $G = \operatorname{Gal}(L|K)=\operatorname{Aut}_K(L)$ and for $\tau\in G$ the character
$$ c_\tau: L^\times \to L, \quad a \mapsto \tau(a).  $$ Let $\sigma\in G$ be a generator of order $n$.
By linear independence of the characters $c_{\sigma^0},\ldots,c_{\sigma^{n-1}}$ there is some $\gamma\in L^\times$ s.t.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}z^i \sigma^i(\gamma)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} z^i c_\sigma(\gamma) \neq 0.$$